# Creating a jQuery like "$" object

Tags: javascript, function

My end goal is being able to do something like this:

```
MyVar(parameter).functionToPerform();
```

Silly enough, even after reading up on how variables are declared, looking at the jQuery code, ... I still can't get my head around it.

This is what I've tried so far, but it fails:

```
var MyClass = function(context) {
this.print = function(){
    console.log("Printing");
}

this.move = function(){
    console.log(context);
}
};

var test = new MyClass();
test.print(); // Works
console.log('Moving: ' + test('azerty').move() ); // Type property error
```

Comment: `test(...)` is not the same as `new test(...)`. :)

Comment: I wrote an article describing concept of creating this kind of simple library: http://dfsq.info/site/read/writing-your-own-jquery

Comment: see my answer for simple [Javascript library like jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505721)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`jQuery()` is both a module with global methods, and a constructor. It automatically calls a constructor if it needs to.  If we are not called with a `new` keyword, then `this` will not have been constructed with `MyClass`.  We can detect that and call the function in constructor mode instead.  Once we do that, then `this` will be an instance of `MyClass` and we can start adding stuff to it.

```
var MyClass = function(context) {
    // if the function is called without being called as a constructor,
    // then call as a constructor for us.
    if (this.__proto__.constructor !== MyClass) {
        return new MyClass(context);
    }

    // Save the context
    this.context = context;

    // methods...
    this.print = function() {
        return "Printing";
    }

    this.move = function() {
        return this.context;
    }
};

$('#output').append('<li>print(): '+ MyClass().print() +'</li>');
$('#output').append('<li>move():'+ MyClass('azerty').move() +'</li>');
$('#output').append('<li>context: '+ MyClass('azerty').context +'</li>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rvvBr/1/

Comment: Now I get it. It still needs to be instantiated, but that can be done from the inside. Pretty cool, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help!  Also, I just updated my answer with a better way to detect if it being called as a constructor or not by actually checking the constructor of the prototype of `this`.  Should be much more robust.

Comment: Even though it works how I want it to I just realized that (because it's being instantiated for every MyClass() call) it's quite slow for my purpose. You live and learn :P

Answer (score 19):

As I write this, Squeegy's answer has the highest number of votes: 7. Yet it is wrong because `__proto__` is non-standard and is not supported by Internet Explorer (even version 8). However, getting rid of `__proto__` does not get it working either in IE 6.

This (somewhat simplified) is the way jQuery actually does it ([even try it on IE 6](http://jsfiddle.net/rvvBr/6/)), and it also includes examples of static methods and method chaining. For all the details of how jQuery does it, of course, you will have to check the [jQuery source code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js) yourself.

```
var MyClass = function(context) {
    // Call the constructor
    return new MyClass.init(context);
};

// Static methods
MyClass.init = function(context) {
    // Save the context
    this.context = context;
};
MyClass.messageBox = function(str) {
    alert(str);
};


// Instance methods
MyClass.init.prototype.print = function() {
    return "Printing";
};
MyClass.init.prototype.move = function() {
    return this.context;
};

// Method chaining example
MyClass.init.prototype.flash = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ffc';
    setInterval(function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }, 5000);
    return this;
};


$('#output').append('<li>print(): '+ MyClass().print() +'</li>');
$('#output').append('<li>flash().move():'+ MyClass('azerty').flash().move() +'</li>');
$('#output').append('<li>context: '+ MyClass('azerty').context +'</li>');
MyClass.messageBox('Hello, world!');
```

Note that if you need "private" data, you will have to put instance methods inside `MyClass.init` (with a variable declared just inside that function) as `this.print = function() { ... };` instead of using `MyClass.init.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently worked on an exercise that asked to re-create a JQuery like  library using ES6 only.

From the points above I was able to create the instantiation logic that makes it possible to call methods on selectors e.g class names.

When the instance of $T is called with a selector a new instance of the $TLib is created on the particular selector which will contain all of the methods that can be used on the selector with the elements in context.

I've added a couple of methods which are chainable in the example below which allows you to add a CSS class to an element and remove the same class in one call e.g:

```
$T('.class-selector').addClass('green').removeClass('green);
```

For those wanting to bootstrap something similar:

```
const $T = (selector) => {
  // returns the HTML elements that match the selector
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return new $TLib(elements, selector);
};

class $TLib {
  constructor (elements) {
    this._elements = elements;
  }

  addClass (className) {
    this._elements.forEach((element) => element.classList.add(className));
    return this;
  }

  removeClass (className) {
    this._elements.forEach((element) => element.classList.remove(className));
    return this;
  }

  toggleClass (className) {
    this._elements.forEach((element) => {
      const classList = element.classList;
      (classList.contains(className)) ? classList.remove(className) : classList.add(className);
    });
    return this;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you do

```
var test = new MyClass()
```

you create an object that has two attributes `move` and `print`. You object `test` is no more a function because of the `new` statement. So calling `test()` is wrong.

Comment: calling `test().move()` is wrong if you are trying to instantiate a `test` object, however chaining function calls (key to jQuery's implementation) is very possible.

Answer (score 1):

every time you call `$` in jQuery it returns a new `jQuery.init` object. The `jQuery.init` object has functions that are then called.

```
function test(type)
{
  switch (type)
  {
    case 'azerty':
      return new type.a();
    case 'qwerty':
    default:
      return new type.b();
  }
}

test.a = function()
{
  //a object defined
};

test.a.prototype.move = function()
{
  //move function defined for the a object
};

etc...
```

I just typed this on the fly, so it may need some tweaking

This would allow you to call `test('azerty').move();`. More importantly: I hope you can see the general structure being used.

Edit to add:

To continue chaining functions like in jQuery, make sure you return the `this` object at the end of each function call:

```
test.a.prototype.move = function()
{
  //move function defined for the a object
  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Probably] The Most Elegant Solution

First off, jQuery uses a pattern which is closer to a *Monad*, a *Factory*, or a combination of both. Nevertheless, here's what I've been using in my projects because the pattern, itself, is so loosely coupled to whatever class you'd like to utilize:

```
;(function (undefined) {
    if (undefined) return;
    var ENV = this;

    var Class = function Class() {
        var thus = this;

        function find(data) {
            console.log('@find #data', data);
            return this;
        }

        function show(data) {
            console.log('@show #data', data);
            return this;
        }

        // export precepts
        this.find = find;
        this.show = show;

        return this;
    };

    var Namespace = ENV['N'] = new (function Namespace(Class) {
        var thus = this;

        var Ns = Class.apply(function Ns(data) {

            if (this instanceof N) {
              return new Namespace(Class);
            }

            return Ns.find.apply(Ns, arguments);
        });


        return Ns;
    })(Class);

}).call(window || new function Scope() {});

var n = N('#id').show(450);
var m = new N();

m('#id')('.curried').show('slow');

console.log(n !== m);  // >> true
```

Basically, you can use it as a function, an object, and use the `new` keyword to construct another unique object/function. You can use this to enforce an *arbiter* method (default, like the `find` method above), or use different methods based upon what parameters are input. For instance, you can do something like:

```
var elementsList = N('#id1')('#id2')('#otherSpecialElement').each(fn);
```

-- OR --

```
var general = N('.things');
var specific = general('.specific')('[data-more-specific]').show();
```

The above would, for instance, accumulate a nodelist of multiple elements (1st expression), or *drill down to one specific element* (2nd).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the 'azerty' value as parameter to MyClass constructor and change the test('azerty').move() to test.move()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyClass = function(context) { 
        this.print = function(){     
            console.log("Printing"); 
        }  
        this.move = function(){     
        console.log(context); 
        return context;
        } 
    };  
    var test = new MyClass('azerty'); 
    test.print(); // Works 
    console.log('Moving: ' + test.move() ); // Type property error 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided so far don't seem to reflect jQuery's exact structure (or jQuery changed over time).

I recently wanted to create an object (similar to jQuery) and came across this question. So here's my answer:

```js
// dummy text element 
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerText = "Lorem ipsum...";


// jQuery-like object
var CustomObject = function (element) {
    return new CustomObject.prototype.init(element);
};

// constructor
CustomObject.prototype.init = function (element) {
    this.el = element;
    this.text = element.innerText;
};

// instance methods
CustomObject.prototype.log = function () {
    console.log(this.text);
    // by returning "this" at the end of instance methods
    // we make these methods chainable
    return this;
};

CustomObject.prototype.add2body = function (delay) {
    document.body.appendChild(this.el);
    return this;
};

// all the instance methods are added to CustomObject, not to CustomObject.init (constructor)
// calling CustomObject() returns a CustomObject.init object, not CustomObject object
// so by default, instance methods are not accessible
// to fix this, you need to assign the prototype of CustomObject to CustomObject.prototype.init
CustomObject.prototype.init.prototype = CustomObject.prototype;

// testing
var obj = CustomObject(p).add2body().log();
```