# JS anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, html, anonymous-function, anonymous

my problem is that I want to call a function like:

```
$('div').doSomething('xyz');
```

and my js-code is:

```
var $ = function(element) {
    var doSomething = function(xyz, xzy, zxy) {
        alert(xyz + element);
    };
};
```

but that does not work (I'm new to js anonymous functions), where's the error?

Thanks for help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556110/creating-a-jquery-like-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $ = function(element) {
    // if the function is called without being called as a constructor,
    // then call as a constructor for us.
    // (partially borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556110/creating-a-jquery-like-object )
    if (this.constructor !== $) {
        return new $(element);
    }
    this.doSomething = function(txt) {
        alert(txt + element);
    };
};
```

Comment: firebug output: $('div') is undefined

Comment: @idealmachine Edited to fix using your comment.  Oops.

Comment: Will not work in IE - it doesn't support the non-standard __proto__

Comment: Thanks for your immediate help!

Comment: I tried removing `__proto__` to access `this.constructor` directly and it seems to be working in both Chrome and IE now.

Comment: @idealmachine Is there some way you know of that will work in IE 6 too?

Comment: I added another answer to the question I linked to. It involves using another function, but it also makes other improvements to the top-voted example.

Comment: okay, but I've got stuck on another problem: alert(txt + element) is working fine, but if I want to access y = document.getElementById(element); y.style.width = 500 + 'px'; it says that y is null

Comment: @pbcoder it would be easier (and more useful) to add that as a new question, rather than to have an extended conversation in the comments.  The rule of thumb is one question per, well, "question".

Comment: @NickAldwin: Chrome shows: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'doSomething' (anonymous function), so it's not compatible with chrome

Comment: @pbcoder Are you sure you typed it right?  I'm testing this code: http://www.jsfiddle.net/PgCtV/ and it's working fine on Chrome