# How does jQuery library use $ in place of "JQuery" to reference objects?

Tags: jquery, object, shorthand

I want to have a shorthand like the `$` symbol as used by `JQuery` for quick reference to an object that is widely used throughout my code.

How can it be done?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556110/creating-a-jquery-like-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` in jQuery is just a JavaScript variable name;

```
var $ = 5;
```

Or if you want to add functionality

```
var $ = {};
$.myMethod = function(){ 
    console.log("Hello");
};
```

See [this book section](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailnamespacing) about namespacing and modules.

What jQuery does in its source code:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

They just assign an object reference to the object `jQuery` to `window.$`

Comment: Or `var $ = someOtherFunctionOrObject` given the question title is asking how to use a short name as shorthand for a longer name (where both names would refer to the same object).