# How do I implement a Chaining Pattern like jQuery does?

Tags: javascript, function

How do I create a prefix like the one jQuery uses? For example, in jQuery I can use:

```
$(".footer").css('display', 'none');
```

and I'd like to enable a similar syntax, like this:

```
google('.footer').chrome('display', 'none');
```

I have searched Google for an answer, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Maybe you can open the Source Code of jQuery and see how they made it.
(Talvez olhando o Código fonte do jQuery você consiga ver como eles fizeram.)

Comment: You want to rename the JQuery? Or do you want to chain function calls like jQuery? (Voce quer renomear o jquery pra outra coisa, eh isso? Ou vc quer fazer uma funcao que funcione de forma encadeada como o jquery?)

Comment: Iago, welcome to stack overflow! In this site, you have to ask in English. Hopefully the possible duplicate I linked will help (bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow; aqui você tem de perguntar em inglês. Espero que o link que postei acima te ajude).

Comment: Also, this will probably interest you (will probably become a real site in the future; for now, it's just a proposal) - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese

Comment: so, I wanted to do kind of a api for a website that Foce equal to the prefix of Jquery to avoid complications. but I can not find how to do this.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, I'm new here and did not know that detail, I thought it had more people here in Brazil.

Comment: But I do not want to make a plugin for jQuery, but do a prefix like him: `a('#ooo').b('ffff');`

Comment: Sorry, I linked to the wrong post. See http://blog.buymeasoda.com/creating-a-jquery-like-chaining-api/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556110/creating-a-jquery-like-object

Comment: @bfavaretto Your link is dead.

Comment: @hsym That comment is too old to be edited. But you can always find dead stuff like that [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130213184346/http://blog.buymeasoda.com/creating-a-jquery-like-chaining-api/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a detailed explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

But the right way to implement is show bellow:

```
var google = function(valor){
    var lalala = '3';

    this.chrome = function(valor){
        console.log(lalala + ' ' + valor);
        return this;
    }

    this.firefox = function(valor){
        console.log(lalala + ' ' + valor);
        return this;
    }

    console.log(valor);

    return this;
};

console.log('first call');
google('testando').chrome('stack');

console.log('second call');
google('testando').chrome('stack').firefox('test');
```

As you could see the key is to **return the object itself** on each function.

You could see the [live code at jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/zipab/1/watch?js,console)

Comment: If you make the method return `this`, you can use it like `google('testando').chrome('stack').chrome('overflow');` :-) Note that this is much simpler than what jQuery does, but does enable the syntax the question is asking about.

Comment: yes, did you remember what's the name of this pattern?

Comment: Thanks Claudio Santos, but his example worked, but I guess it did not work for what I wanted to do.

Think about this: to change the value of an element:

<div id="Google">Search</div>


`    var google = function(element){
      chrome: function(html){
        document.querySelectorAll(element).innerHTML = html;
      }
    }`

Comment: @IagoBruno the problem was that chrome() didn't return a string, please see the [upgrade code](http://jsfiddle.net/csantos/Z3kra/1/)

Comment: yes, look at my example does not work, so I was doing dear, something that works is the same as jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/iagob26/DwR2K/1/

Comment: Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/csantos/DwR2K/2/) now

Comment: @IagoBruno `querySelectorAll` returns a list of elements, you have to loop: http://jsfiddle.net/TBNQ8/2/

Comment: Oh, Thank you bfavaretto and Claudio Santos, that was the result I wanted! ^_^

Comment: one more thing, do you know if this document.querySelectorAll has support for multiple browsers? Or do you think I should use document.getElementsByClassName?

Comment: I don't know, but I could bet that you'll have problems, so try to use jquery.(if this answer solve your problem please mark as an answer)

Comment: The intention is to not use jQuery, but I will not use querySelector.

Comment: @IagoBruno `querySelectorAll` is supported in IE8+ (partial support reported on IE8). See http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll.