# Javascript Multiline Commands

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, Is it Possible to write Multi-Line Statement like as follows;

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "Something"; 
                            .style.display = "some";
                            .style.color = "#CCC";
```

Hope you got the Idea?

Comment: With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/): `$('#ID').html('Something').css({ display: 'some', color: '#CCC' })`, you can put line breaks before the method calls obviously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I implement a Chaining Pattern like jQuery does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862623/how-do-i-implement-a-chaining-pattern-like-jquery-does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can't write like this but can use this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("ID");
obj.innerHTML = "Something"; 
obj.style.display = "some";
obj.style.color = "#CCC";
```

Because to call any property in javascript there is need the object on which you want to apply that property.

Answer (score 1):

Take `document.getElementById("ID")` into a variable.

Like

```
var eleId = document.getElementById("ID");

eleId.innerHTML = "Something"; 
eleId.style.display = "some";
eleId.style.color = "#CCC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends, in the example you have provided you cant do that, you can only do that when you call a function that also returns a function a good example is jQuery, lets take a look.

```
$('#something') // <-- select a element - returns a whole object of functions 
               .hide() // hide function was returned
               .show() // show function was returned
               .css(...);
```

In your example the string that you set was actually returned.

This is how you make a chaining function.

```
var test = function( name ) {
   this.name = name;
   return this;
};

test.prototype.viewName = function() {
   console.log(this.name);
};

test.prototype.showName = function() {
    alert(this.name);
    return this;
};
var john = new test('john');
john.showName().viewName();
```

So in your case you would have to store the object

```
var element = document.getElementById("ID");
    element.innerHTML = "Something"; 
    element.style.display = "some";
    element.style.color = "#CCC";
```

So it all depends on what is returned from your last action.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is, but not in your case.

It is possible when you call several **functions** which return the same obj over and over again, for instance in jQuery:

`$('#el').fadeIn().fadeOut();`

It's called `Cascade` (Well, Douglas Crockford called it like that, you can find it in his book `Javascript: The Good Parts`)

In your case you cannot do that (at least with vanilla javascript).

```
var el = document.getElementById("ID")

el.innerHTML = "Something"; 
el.style.display = "some";
el.style.color = "#CCC";
```